# How can I achieve a smoother curve for polylines in Leaflet?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, curve, polyline

I am using Leaflet to display to draw a polyline on a map, but the default rendering results in jagged curves. I would like to achieve a smoother curve for my polylines in Leaflet. What are some approaches or techniques I can use to achieve this? Are there any specific libraries or plugins available that can help me accomplish this?

```
drawRoute() {
    this.map.dragging.disable();
    this.map.removeEventListener('mousedown');
    this.map.removeEventListener('mousemove');
    this.map.removeEventListener('mouseup');
    const trace = this.data.trace;
    this.map.on('mousedown', (event) => {
      if (event.originalEvent.button === 0) {

        if (trace.type == 'primary') {
          this.polyline = L.polyline([event.latlng], {
            ...trace,
            smoothFactor: 1,
          }).addTo(this.map);
        } else {
          this.secondaryPolyline = L.polyline([event.latlng], {
            weight: trace.weight,
            opacity: trace.opacity,
            smoothFactor: 1,
          }).addTo(this.map);
        }
        this.map.on('mousemove', (event) => {
          if (trace.type == 'primary') {
            if (!this.polyline) return;
            this.common.lineExist.next(true);
            this.polyline.addLatLng(event.latlng);
          } else {
            if (!this.secondaryPolyline) return;
            this.secondaryPolyline.addLatLng(event.latlng);
          }
        });
      }
    });
    this.map.on('mouseup', (event) => {
      if (event.originalEvent.button === 0) {
        this.map.removeEventListener('mousedown');
        this.map.removeEventListener('mouseup');
        this.map.removeEventListener('mousemove');
        this.map.dragging.enable();
      }
    });
  }
```

this is the code example it allow me to draw a polyline on map free handly but the line is not smooth i want it to be smoother on curves